# How to sort list of class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

I have list of  model class object. class scoreboard which have total score as one property.

```
Scoreboard scoreboard = new Scoreboard();
```

I am sorting list like this

```
data= data.OrderByDescending(x => x.totalScore).ToList()
```

but wont work.
please what should I do the list is of object of class.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What results do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you be more specific? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: what is the property for score inside scoreboard class?

Comment: the list have all element in string format but class have int datatype.sorry class also have string datatype of totalscore.doesnot working means the order I was got is wrong like 2,452,45,42 like this.

Comment: Why are you sorting 'data' when your scores are in 'scoreboard'.  Please show how 'data' and 'scoreboard' are related?

Comment: Change `totalScore` to typeof `int` of another numeric type (you cannot sort b numeric value when its typeof `string`)

Comment: Thanks buddies I got problem the class have string datatype of _totalscore  that's why its not working any way this solve my problem I make it int now.Thanks a lot @codelahiru

Comment: good to hear. I thought it is a one property list. Then you can use linq operations.

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke its works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your sorting issue correctly, this might help

```
    List<Class1> Scores = new List<Class1>();
    Scores.Add(new Class1 { Score = 1, TotalScore = 2, User = "A" });
    Scores.Add(new Class1 { Score = 1, TotalScore = 5, User = "B" });
    Scores.Add(new Class1 { Score = 1, TotalScore = 3, User = "C" });

    Scores = Scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalScore).ToList();
```

This will sort it by total score.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your score if you have the data like below as one property,

```
List<int> scoreData = new List<int>();
            scoreData.Add(300);
            scoreData.Add(201);
            scoreData.Add(400);
```

Then to sort,

```
var sortedData = data.Sort();
```